# SQL arithmetic in single pass

Tags: sql

How do I compute the ratio of `completed` to `total` in a single pass of SELECT ?

Currently the only way I know how is this:

```sql
SELECT 
    Pers_Name, completed, total, completed/total AS ratio
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Pers_Name,
         SUM(CASE state WHEN 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed, 
         COUNT(booking_code) AS total
     FROM 
         mytable
     GROUP BY 
         Pers_Name)


+---------+---------+-----+-------------------+
|Pers_Name|completed|total|              ratio|
+---------+---------+-----+-------------------+
|   216094|       11|   14| 0.7857142857142857|
|  4149516|       10|   17| 0.5882352941176471|
|  3702541|        9|   10|                0.9|
|  2865918|       16|   21| 0.7619047619047619|
|  1721810|       14|   23| 0.6086956521739131|
+---------+---------+-----+-------------------+
```

But this does not work:

```sql
SELECT 
    Pers_Name,
    SUM(CASE state WHEN 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed, 
    COUNT(booking_code) AS total,
    completed/total AS ratio
FROM 
    mytable
GROUP BY 
    Pers_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avg()`:

```
SELECT Pers_Name,
       SUM(case state when 'COMPLETED' then 1 else 0 end) as completed_cnt, 
       AVG(case state when 'COMPLETED' then 1.0 else 0 end) as completed_ratio 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Pers_Name;
```

Note though that your notion of "single pass" really has no place in SQL.  The optimizer chooses how to execute the query.  The `SELECT` statement describes what the result set looks like, but does not specify *how* it is produced.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! However i with an additional caveat that i want to see all 3 `completed` `total` as well as `ratio`, it means i need to compute `case state when 'COMPLETED' then 1.0 else 0 end` twice ?